# How to merge two scala list in to another list without using built in functions

Tags: scala

```
val l1 = List(1,2)
val l2 = List(3,4)
```

I know that there is List.concat(l1,l2) will merge these two lists and create a new list . But is there any way to achieve it without using built-in methods

I tried the below code but not helped

```
for(i <- l1; j <- l2){
  List.add(i,j)
}
```

I want result  as List(1,2,3,4)  but i dont want to use concat or :::, or ++

Please help

Comment: Sure... there are a millions ways you can do it `List(l1, l2).flatten`, `l2.foldLeft(le)((r, a) => r :+ a)`, `l2.prependedAll(l1)`. In a rich language like Scala an expression can be rewritten to an semantic equivalent a million ways.  If your question is "can I do it without using **any** function defined on `List` then the answer is of course not. `List` is has an interface that defines how you can construct it and you have to play by those rules. That is the whole point of Objects. Delegation of who defines these rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose from this several options, I do not know if *List.concat(l1,l2)* is something that will fit your needs, but I added for case if it will fit:

```
  val l1 = List(1, 2)
  val l2 = List(3, 4, 5)
  
  def merge(l1: List[Int], l2: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    @tailrec
    def loop(l1: Vector[Int], l2: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
      l1.lastOption match {
        case Some(x) => loop(l1.dropRight(1), x +: l2)
        case None => l2
      }
    }

    loop(l1.toVector, l2)
  }

  println(merge(l1, l2))
```

This example just use *foldLeft* function to concatenate second *List* to first one:

```
  val l1 = List(1, 2)
  val l2 = List(3, 4, 5)

  val concatenatedList: List[Int] = l1.toVector.foldRight(l2)((el, result) => el +: result)
  println(concatenatedList)
```

Also, as written in the comments do not use :+ on the Lists, because add to the end of the list takes O(n) time, but if you use +: it takes constant time.

Comment: That's really not a very good implementation of concat. Appending to a `List` on each iteration is definitely not good practice. At the very least use prepend and then `reverse`, but can be much simpler than this code. This code also interleaves rather than concatenating ...

Comment: I agree with you and I wrote that better to use built in functions, but I just show some examples how it is possible to do by the code that I saw above. 
`for(i <- l1; j <- l2){
  List.add(i,j)
}` It looks for me like attempt to iterate by each element, so I suggested such options like this.

Comment: The example makes it very clear that the OP is looking for concatenation not interleave or cartesian product, so a poor implementation of interleave is not, in my view, a good answer.

Comment: Yes, looks like I miss understand the question. I fixed solution. Thank you!